# Very weird behavior of android 4.2.2+ (Actionbar)

Tags: java, android

I'm using in my app a method to display a actionbar when >= API 11 otherwise display custombar.
All fine, works perfect on 3.0+

But, when starting my app on 4.2.2 , 4.4.2 the actionbar AND the custom bar both are not showing....

This is my code for this part:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
   final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
   actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);         
}else{
   RelativeLayout actionBar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.customActionBar);
   actionBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Well this is strange right? Should just show the actionbar.
Help is really appriciated!

Comment: Your logic is incorrect for version 11, which will display an ActionBar rather than the custom bar...

Comment: The code statement is correct. If its api 11 it will also be capable to show a actionbar. Like i said 3.0+ works and shows the actionbar, less then 3.0 shows a custom one, but when going to 4.2.2+ it doesn't show any of those, and just displays nothing..

Comment: If the code statement is correct, then your description isn't: "I'm using in my app a method to display a custom bar on api =< 11 otherwise display actionbar."

Comment: I was just about to type that, but this forum is about code. My question is, this code is correct, why it doesn't work correctly? Whatever i did type wrong. English isn't my primary language;P (btw my explaination was alright, just in another context, custom bar =< api 3.0 is exactly the same as action bar >= 3.0).

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a forum, and it's about solving problems. When your code doesn't match the description of the problem, it makes it harder to help you. You should edit your post so it's consistent. Now, have you added logging to your app to see which branch is taken in the problematic case?

Comment: The description was alright, just in another context, check my edited comment. But i will edit it for people who don't read properly.. And i did everthing to solve this, otherwise i didn't came to stackoverflow, its my last option.

Comment: No, the description was *not* all right. By the description, you wanted one behaviour for version 11 and lower, and another for strictly greater than 11. Your code shows one behaviour for version 11 and higher, and another for strictly lower than 11. There's nothing contextual about that, and I'm perfectly capable of reading properly. If you're going to be rude to people who are trying to help you (and trying to help you get help from others), you're less likely to receive the help you're looking for.

Comment: Wait wait, i see it now, sec let me try something. Probably did read something wrong, but i see now what you ment. Let me try some things. I update in a sec.

Comment: Meh might had a idea, but nothing works. Everthing works fine , only when the app is on 4.2.2+ it doesn't display the actionbar or custom bar anymore. Something is changed in function after this update?

Comment: No idea, but you add diagnostics to check which branch is taken (via logging), and then edit your post to indicate the results.